# Angular view not updating from within $apply

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, angularjs-scope

I have some code in an Angular directive that looks like the following:

```
    $scope.populateResults = function (list_results) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            console.log("Applying", list_results);
            if (list_results.attractions.length === 0) console.log("Empty list");
            $scope.attractionsList.list_results = [];
            $.each(list_results.attractions, function(index, attraction) {
                console.log("executing for each");
                if (attraction) {
                    attraction.addedWaypoint = false;
                    $scope.attractionsList.list_results.push(attraction);
                }
            });
            console.log($scope.attractionsList.list_results);
        });
    };
```

The function is passed as a callback to an AJAX request that is handled in another file.  The console.log statements all print everything as expected, but the view does not change.  When I print the value of $scope.attractionsList.list_results in another function, it shows that the list is empty.  Shouldn't the fact that the $scope variable is changed in an $apply function mean that the view would be updated?  This only happens occasionally.  I don't see any errors coming back from the AJAX request, and all the console.log's in the $.each loop print as expected.  Where else should I look for this bug?

Comment: You are like already in scope method...why you need apply?

Comment: What version of angular are you using?